# python decode('hex') return empty ASCII string

Tags: string, python-2.7

I try to encrypt all zeros using the crypto library. However, after I do the decode, the value is gone. How can I get the ASCII value after the decode hex?

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
#..
#.. cipher initialization
#..

ctr_a = ctr.decode("hex") #hex coded string to hex string
print ctr
print ctr_a
temp = obj.encrypt(str(ctr_a))
```

output

```
ctr = 00000000000000000000000000000000
ctr_a =
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not empty, it's just that 00 is a null character which displays nothing in a terminal

```
ctr = "00000000000000000000000000000000"
ctr_a = ctr.decode("hex") #hex coded string to hex string
print ctr
print len(ctr_a)
```

returns

```
00000000000000000000000000000000
16
```

If you change one of the sets to a character that will render to the screen you will see the difference

```
ctr = "00650000000000000000000000000000"
ctr_a = ctr.decode("hex") #hex coded string to hex string
print ctr
print len(ctr_a)
print '"%s"' % ctr_a
```

outputs

```
00650000000000000000000000000000
16
"e"
```